# Perl Regular expression extract

Tags: perl

I'm trying to extract a certain string of numbers from a text file using a regular exression, but when my code runs, it is grabbing the numbers after the slash in the separation between date and time. Here is what I have so far.

```
while ( <INFILE> ) {

    my @fields = split( /\ /, $_ );
    my @output;

    foreach my $field ( @fields ) {
        if ( $field =~ /[0-9]{5}\// ) {
            push @output, $field;
        }
    }

    if ( @output ) {
        my $line = join( ' ', @output );
        print "$line\n";
        print OUTFILE "$line\n";
    }
}
```

The line I am trying to extract data from is

```
D2001235 9204 254/2004 254/1944 254/2041 15254/2011 ALL-V4YM 001 AUTO C-C0000
```

The data I need is the `15254` but when I run my code it returns `15254/2011` and my program is erroring out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing the entire `$field` in the output array, but you only want the number to the left of the slash to be stored.  You could use capturing parentheses in the regular expression and the `$1` special variable.  This outputs `15254`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split( /\ /, $_ );
    my @output;
    foreach my $field (@fields) {
        if ( $field =~ /^([0-9]{5})\// ) {
            push @output, $1;
        }
    }
    if (@output) {
        my $line = join( ' ', @output );
        print "$line\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
D2001235 9204 254/2004 254/1944 254/2041 15254/2011 ALL-V4YM 001 AUTO C-C0000
```

Comment: You can also use `my ($value) = $field =~ m,^(\d{5})\/,;` if you don't like `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained, you are saving an entire field in `@output` if it matches the regex, instead of just the first part before the slash

Your `split` is also unnecessarily complicated, and `join` isn't needed

All you need is this

```
while ( <INFILE> ) {

    my @output = map m{^([0-9]{5})/}, split;

    if ( @output ) {
        print "@output\n";
        print OUTFILE "@output\n";
    }
}
```